# KnockoutJS with IndexedDB - DataCloneError

Tags: knockout.js, indexeddb

When I save an observable to IndexedDB, I get a DataCloneError.

E.g. using IDBWrapper: https://github.com/jensarps/IDBWrapper

```
store = new IDBStore({
    storeName: 'myStore',
    keyPath: 'Id',
    autoIncrement: true,
    onStoreReady: loadCallback
});

...

var myObservable = ko.observable("value");

...

store.put(myObservable, refreshCallback);
```

What would be the best way of working around this? Has anyone tackled this yet?

I have quite a complicated observableArray of object that contains observables and non-observables, so just grabbing the values out would be a bit repetitive.

**UPDATE:**

So far I have tried `ko.toJS` which is promising (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) however because I am also using an isDirty flag with some of my observables (see here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) this gets converted to a function so I'd need to deal with that manually anyway... I could to `ko.toJSON` so the whole thing gets stringified but then would it be harder to convert that back to the observable format compared to just manually setting each value?

So currently I am just doing this:

```
var myObservable = ko.observable("value")

...

var plainValue = myObservable();
store.put(plainValue, refreshCallback);
```

Only I have an observableArray of varying contents, so I have to do a lot of checks to see if values are observable or not, and if so then unwrap them and store them separately. Seems a bit messy. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Show the code you're using to save the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataCloneError occur when the object [could not be serialized](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#exceptions). I prefer plain old javascript object (JSON) to store in indexeddb. So, your solution is preferable. Generally I will have constructor for `myObservable` from JSON serialized object. It is clean and future proof. For some reason, if you want to change `myObservable`, you can still instantiate from old and new JSON.